# Mysql error when program is built

Tags: c#, mysql, visual-studio, build, publish

I have a program called 'MYSQLprogram', it contains some simple Mysql database connections.

```
MySqlConnection Conn = 
    new MySqlConnection(datasource=localhost;port=3306;username=root;password=);
conn.Open();
String Insert = "INSERT INTO DataBase.Row (id, name) VALUES (NULL, "hagbard");";
MySqlCommand CMD = new MySqlCommand(Insert, Conn);
CMD.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

^This code works perfectly fine in VisualStudio.

---

When the program is built(Published) I get the error:

```
Unable to connect to any of the specified MySql hosts.
```

---

The published program uses the exact same code as the original-program that runs inside VisualStudio and I cant find anyone on the web that has encountered the problem.

Comment: Does the machine you're running on have MySQL running?

Comment: That code wouldn't even compile... your connection string isn't in a string, and your string literal for the insert isn't a valid literal either. But if it did, you're trying to connect to a locally-running MySQL server, listening on port 3306. *Is* there such a server in your published environment?

Comment: And your insert-statement is also not valid.

Comment: @JonSkeet oh, my bad... I compressed it from my program, it's Properties.Settings.Default.db_connection by default.

Comment: @JonSkeet Yes, I am running a local MySql using "EasyPHP", same as I use when testing in VisualStudio, so everything is the same.

Comment: Well clearly *something* is not the same. Do you have anything to reassure you that MySQL really *is* accessible on that machine, on that port, with that username and password?

Comment: @JonSkeet http://sv.tinypic.com/r/359gzr8/8

Comment: Well that's evidence that the app isn't working - I believe that. I asked you for evidence that MySQL is accessible on that machine and port with the right username and password. Have you got *something else* which can talk to it, from the same machine?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to change:

```
String Insert = "INSERT INTO DataBase.Row (id, name) VALUES (NULL, "hagbard");";
```

to:

```
String Insert = "INSERT INTO `Database`.`Row`(id, name) values('" + NULL+ "','" + hagbard + "';)";
```

I hope this will solve your problem. Have a nice day!